# Can 2x6 ceiling joists support a temporary point source load of 1500#

Tags: framing, ceiling, structural, engineering

I’m installing a residential elevator in my home. The installation requires a [padeye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padeye) in the ceiling to carry 1500 lbs. I have 2x6” ceiling joists spanning 16’. I planned to bridge a 2x10 across two joists in the attic and pass the padeye post through it from below to carry the load. The padeye is 5/8” diameter rated for 5000 lbs. Will the ceiling joists and 2x10 bridge be sufficient to temporarily carry the 1500 lb load?

Comment: Define "temporary" please. How will you bridge the 2x10? to the joists?

Comment: For those of us not familiar with the term, what's a "padeye"?

Comment: 16 foot span, 2x6, 1500lbs.  Not something I would stand under.

Comment: Wow, what's the purpose of doing this temporarily? Shoot for permanent and you might find that the 2x10 might not even be sufficient. Consult an engineer because it sounds like you might be out of your depth with this project.

Comment: "temporary"? when the beam breaks all it was feeling was the load.

Comment: do you have a photo of the pad eye, how is it attached to the wood beam

Comment: Rough estimate, the 2x6 can carry 30psf.

Comment: Distributing the 1500# load between (2)2x6 members spanning 16'-0" will not be safe. You might want to look into using (4)2x10s Hem Fir No2 or equivalent, (2) each side. 

You will want to reconsider using a flat 2x10 as well, there is no way that's strong enough. Not to mention the screws that would be required to hold that padeye in place. Just because the padeye is rated for 5000# doesn't mean the connection from the screw to the wood is.

Comment: @represton, answers go down there.

Comment: Seems to me you should be looking at putting in some posts up to the attic with a beam sitting on them that you fasten your padeye to. This would require you to get the right size beam, maybe a steel I-beam and make sure your posts are sitting on appropriate support. As is I'd say @isherwood answered your question. I think you need to look at a different design for this.

Answer (score 2):

No. At least not safely or wisely.

16' is a really long span for a 2x6, even as just a ceiling. Even with two of them you'd have massive sag, and if either aren't very robust specimens I wouldn't be surprised by catastrophic failure. Even if they were up to the task, tip/twist is a real possibility without boxing or bracing. That would mean game over.

Comment: Thanks to all. I think I’ll double the 2x10 and run perpendicular from the rim joist across three ceiling joists with a steel post below to carry the load.

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to resolve your posts.